# How do I get the value from an ArrayList by using an "external" variable for comparing in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, data-class

I am trying to get one value from an Array with a data class in an elegant way depending on a Boolean type value. Here is an example:

```
...
private val isDone = true/false
...
private fun color(key: String): Int {
    val colors = arrayListOf(
        Color(TEXT, R.color.text_light, R.color.text_night),
        Color(BACK, R.color.background_light, R.color.background_night),
        ...
    )

    //Wanna achieve something like this
    val color = colors.find { it.key == key }.if { isDone } // if Done is true, the colorA should be retured, if not then the colorB.

    return color 
}
```

This is the date class I use:

```
data class Color(val key: String, @ColorRes val colorA: Int, @ColorRes val colorB: Int)
```

Is there a simple way by using some extensions of ArrayList to achieve that? I do not want to use `.forEach` loop or similar.

Comment: Terminology: an `ArrayList` is not an array. It's a `List`. (One which happens to be implemented using an array, but that's invisible.) Most collection classes (and many others) are named as _<implementation><interface>_, so `LinkedList` is a `List` which is implemented using a linked series of nodes, and `HashMap` is a `Map` that happens to be implemented using a hash table. In this case, I don't think it matters what type of list you use, so you're probably better of using `listOf()` and letting the language pick the most appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "some extensions of `ArrayList`" is `find`, which you are already using.

After we find it, we can use `let` to bind the found color to a name, and then use an if expression to check `isDone`.

```
val color = colors.find { it.key == key }?.let { found -> 
    if (isDone) { found.colorA } else { found.colorB }
}
```

Note that `color` is of type `Int?`. It is nullable because it will be null when `key` is *not* found. You should think about what to do when this happens.

Also note that `isDone` is a `val`, which is likely to be unintentional (?)

Comment: Thank you so much. This looks better than. Also, thanks for notes.

Comment: you don't need the curly braces in an if/else expression, I would also not use the rather meaningless variable `found` but just stick to the equally meaningless default `it`, but that's just me

Comment: @somethingsomething I am aware :) I like to have braces so that it can more easily become multiline later down the line, and I named the lambda parameter in this case because `found` after `find` just looks so fitting!